# Probability of ace on flop?

Tags: probability, poker-tools

I would like to ask.  If someone has an AQ and I have got AJ what's the probability of hitting an A on the flop?

Answer (score 3):

Assuming heads-up. Since you hold AQ and villain has AJ, 
there are 52-4=48 cards left on the deck, with 2 Aces remaining.

So,

Prob[at least an Ace on the Flop] = 1-Prob[no Ace on Flop]=1-(46/48)*(45/47)*(44/46) = 1-0.878
= **12.2%**